# Have I screwed up my boot settings?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a laptop with W7. There were two partitions, the C: with the OS and D: with data. So I got curious about linux and created one more partition from the free space on C:. Then I installed ubuntu in the new partition, now when I turn on the laptop I can only access something through ubuntu. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...so, what happens when you try to "access something" not through Ubuntu? Any errors?

Comment: Well, I'm not given the option to initialize Windows, I though it would give me the option when I turn on the PC.

Comment: you want to run a `sudo update-grub` in terminal

Comment: @Simon i will post it as an answer. as it worked can you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update your boot loader run this command in terminal.

```
sudo update-grub
```

this command will scan for installed operating systems on your Hard Drives and partitions and add them to the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> now when I turn on the laptop I can only access something through
>   ubuntu.

are you saying that computer automatically boots Ubuntu? If so:

1- Some HDDs don't support dual-boot and installs the new OS over the old one (speaking from first hand experience). This might be the case but if you can make sure that it is not then:

2- Try to check your boot options in your BIOS. It might be set to boot Ubuntu directly.

Comment: Yes, it is like W7 doesn't exist. Though I can access the partition with it through Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try option 2 ?